# Алгоритмы работы с map C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, map, итераторы

Суть задания:
реализовать для map 5 алгоритмов sort, copy, none_of, find_if, copy_if.

Начал разбираться, а примеры только для vector находил.

Можете просто для примера написать как правильно работать с этими алгоритмами используя map, а не vector.

Comment: А в книжке по C++, которую вы читали, примеров не было? Ну-ну. Палю годноту: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map, там к каждому методу примеры.

Answer (score 3):

Из этих пяти стандартных алгоритмов вы можете применить к контейнеру `std::map` только алгоритмы `std::copy`, `std::none_of`, `std::find_if` и `std::copy_if`.

Вы не можете применить стандартный алгоритм `std::sort`, потому что контейнер `std::map` в свою очередь является сортированным контейнером по ключу (вы не можете изменить порядок следования элементов), и, во-вторых, стандартный алгоритм `std::sort` требует наличие итератора произвольного доступа, а `std::map` имеет только двусторонний последовательный итератор.

Также имейте в виду, что данный контейнер имеет свои методы, который выполняют поиск, как, например, `find`, `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` и `equal_range`.

Вот пример применения некоторых из перечисленных стандартных алгоритмов к контейнеру `std::map`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> m;

    m[0] = "Peter";
    m[1] = "John";
    m[2] = "Bob";
    m[3] = "Fred";

    for ( const auto &p : m ) std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::map<int, std::string> m2;

    std::copy( m.begin(), m.end(), std::inserter( m2, m2.end() ) );

    for ( const auto &p : m2 ) std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    m2.clear();

    std::copy_if( m.begin(), m.end(), std::inserter( m2, m2.end() ), 
                  []( const std::pair<int, std::string> &p ) { return p.first % 2; } );

    for ( const auto &p : m2 ) std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Neither name is less than 3 characters: "
              << std::boolalpha
              << std::none_of( m.begin(), m.end(), 
                               []( const std::pair<int, std::string> &p ) { return p.second.size() < 3; } )
              << std::endl;

    std::string name = "John";

    auto it = std::find_if( m.begin(), m.end(), 
                            [&name]( const std::pair<int, std::string> &p ) { return p.second == name; } );

    if ( it != m.end() )
    {
        std::cout << it->second << " has key " << it->first << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Name \"" << name << "\" is not found" << std::endl;
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
0: Peter
1: John
2: Bob
3: Fred

0: Peter
1: John
2: Bob
3: Fred

1: John
3: Fred

Neither name is less than 3 characters: true
John has key 1
```